# Find an expression involving only $z$, $\bar z$, $w$, $\bar w$ for $\vec u$ $\cdot$ $\vec v$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a,b,c,d $\in \mathbb R$,

Let $$\vec u=\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b \end{pmatrix}$$ and 
 $$\vec v=\begin{pmatrix}c\\ d \end{pmatrix}$$ 
and let $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$.

Find an
expression involving only $z$, $\bar z$, $w$, $\bar w$ for $\vec u$ $\cdot$ $\vec v$.

$\vec u$ $\cdot$ $\vec v$ = $ac+bd$, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\vec u\cdot \vec v=\frac12(z\overline w+\overline z w)
$$
Because

$$z\overline w=(a+ib)(c-id)=ac+bd+i(bc-ad)$$
and

$$\overline zw=(a-ib)(c+id)=ac+bd-i(bc-ad).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$z\bar{w}=ac-adi+bci+bd.$$